# MongoDB: verifying document was not updated

Tags: mongodb

We would like to apply some auditing in our current project. For that we created a scenario but I don't see how to make point **1** and **2** atomic.

**Scenario**

Every document has to have a `timestamp` that will server 
as a version. When saving a document we will:

1. **Verify document was not changed -** first compare the `timestamps` of the latest document `docLatest` 
   with the document we would like to store `docUpdated`. The `timestamps` must be equal.

   - If not, save request is refused.
   - If ok, go to next point.
2. **Update the document**
3. **Create diff with the previous doc -** The latest document must be our last 
   document. We will create a diff and store it.

Answer (score 1):

I stumble upon this idea once. My idea will utilize long_polling technique. I am not going to tell you how to architect your data, but you can convert date to numeric value, and compare by it.

for 1 and 2, you can convert Date-format to number, the schema will look something like below:

```
var document= { 
   updatedAt: { type: Number, default: Date.parse(new Date()) } 
 }
```

then for every document submitted by client, just check, if the

```
if(latestDocument.updatedAt - prevDocument.updatedAt > 0) {
   //if latest's timestamp is bigger than prev, then store it in mongodb

} else {
  //if latest document is the same or even older, just ignore this document
}
```

for number 3. I found that, if the document has changed, do you even need to diff it? I decide to follow react/flux's method, if the document has changed just replaced the whole document.

Comment: Thx vdj4y! I need to diff it. We will use the diffs for audit logs. 

I stepped upon a more natural solution for mongoDb. Have a look at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html and search for `option: versionKey`. It's prepared for optimistic locking. In my case it would replace `timestamp` with `__v` which is a simple non-negative number. But I can't make the `__v` appear in any of my documents...

Comment: Cool that's very interesting. although in your case I think it's pointless, because I think you want to check if current document is latest, then replace the old value with latest timestamp (to replace not to increment it), so locking might not be needed, unless of course your plan is to increment the version. cheers